# creating pdf reader in android using ionic framwork

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, pdf, ionic-framework

creating pdf reader in ionic using pdf.js it's work perfectly for app folder pdf file  but outside app folder not working my code is.

```
PDFJS.workerSrc = '/lib/pdf/pdf.worker.js';
var filename     = decodeURIComponent($stateParams.pdffile);
alert(filename);

$cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory+"book_folder/",filename).then(function(arraybuffer) {

    var uInt8Arr = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);

    PDFJS.getDocument(uInt8Arr).then(function(pdfFromRaw) {
        pdfFromRaw.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        var canvas = document.getElementById('pdf');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
});
```